# artisan migrate error 140 wrong create options

Tags: laravel, docker, mariadb, laravel-5.5

I've just moved from a Vagrant-based localhost setup to a Docker setup running :

- PHP 7.2.8
- PHP-FPM 7.2.8
- Mariadb 10.2.15 ([webhippie/mariadb](https://hub.docker.com/r/webhippie/mariadb/))

I exec'ed into the Docker machine running FPM and did `php artisan migrate`, but was greeted with the following error :

`` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `data`.`migrations` (errno: 140 "Wrong create options") (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(191) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC) ``

I have another Laravel install running with the same Docker machines and no problem doing migrations.

From the erorr message, it seems there is an error during Laravel's creation of the migrations table. I've no idea what to do next. Help?

---

**UPDATE :**

Tried running the creation query :

`` create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(191) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC ``

Removing option `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` successfully creates the `migrations` table. Will removing it impact Laravel's operation?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer.

I set `engine = 'innodb ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC'` at `config/database.php`. I did this a long time ago when trying to fix [Laravel's key too long error](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error). There is a simple fix (in the link) which limits string length to 191. so to fix the problem, just set `engine = 'innodb'` or `engine = 'null'` at `config/databse.php`.

Comment: 5 choices of solution:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Answer (score 0):

check this out 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/migrations-and-table-options-row-format?page=0

and let me know if it doesn't work

change config/database.php

```
'connections' => [
...
'mysql' => [
    ...
    'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC',
]
...
```